# How to append logs of Pytest into Allure Report

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, allure

How can i get to show all the logs of pytest into Allure. and what are stdout and stderr used for ?

Please check the Highlighted Code which i am referring to
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AePZ.png]

Comment: Any luck with this @Mahesh_Kokare?

Comment: i figured out the way to add logs to Allure and i even make logs as individual steps of Allure this helped a lot to me....thank you guys

Answer (score 8):

The **stdout** and **stderr** are used to display output produced by tests to those steams.
To get them (and **log**) populated in Allure report your test or application executed by test have to produce output to corresponding streams.

```
import logging
import sys

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

def test_001():
    logger.info('Logged INFO message')
    logger.warning('Logged WARNING message')
    logger.error('Logged ERROR message')
    print('Message outputted to stdout')
    print('Message outputted to stderr', file=sys.stderr)
    assert 1 == 1
```

Output from test above:

[image]

Comment: Where are you actually attaching these logs to the report though? Doesn't this have to be done via allure.attach somewhere?

Comment: The log (and stream) output is captured and stored as attachment automatically. The report in screenshot is produced by code above without any additional directives.

Comment: hi, how i can hide this? log stdout stderr

Comment: @Leonid The only way to do this is do not log/print or by adding `--allure-no-capture` option.